# Matrix Scaling level 5 variables

Tags: java, android, matrix

I have 5 variables.

The bitmap width and height.
The screen width and height.
The desired percentage

How do I make the bitmap a desired percentage of the screen using a matrix (I.e 1.0 normal, 0.5 half size, 2.0 double size).

The bitmaps are sprites that are different frame widths (I.E explosion is 200x4000 (20 frames of 200x200 while the object is 65x195 so 65x65 per object if that helps).

My aim is to pass something into ResizeBitmap like (Bitmap, 100) which would be 100% of the screen while keeping the aspect ratio.

So ResizeBitmap(Bitmap, 10) would make it 10% of the screen.

This is what I've got so far, it crashes show's the wrong sizes.

```
public Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int screen_percentage)
{   
    float scale;

    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    float percentage_of_screen;
    float percentage_of_percentage_screen;

    if(screen_width > screen_height)
    {
        percentage_of_screen = (screen_width / 100) * width;
        percentage_of_percentage_screen = (screen_width / 100) * screen_percentage;
        scale = percentage_of_screen / percentage_of_percentage_screen;
    }

    else
    {
        percentage_of_screen = (screen_height / 100) * height;
        percentage_of_percentage_screen = (screen_height / 100) * screen_percentage;
        scale = percentage_of_screen / percentage_of_percentage_screen;
    }

    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

    // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Can anyone fix my code or at least help me because I've wasted so much time on this function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

```
public class StackOverflowActivity extends Activity{

    private int screen_width;
    private int screen_height;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // in main.xml use an ImageView with android:id="@+id/img"
        ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

        // in your drawables folder, put an image named circle.png
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        screen_width = display.getWidth();
        screen_height = display.getHeight();

        Bitmap scale = resizeBitmap(bmp, 100);

        view.setImageBitmap(scale);

    }

    public Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int screen_percentage)
    {
            ////////////// IMPORTANT ////////////////////
            // Use '/ 100.0f' otherwise your percentage will be 0..
            // this will later on, cause the newWidth & newHeight to be 0 as well
            // which causes the app to crash
        float percentage = screen_percentage / 100.0f;

        float scale = screen_width / 100 * percentage;
        if(screen_width < screen_height)
        {
            scale = screen_height / 100 * percentage;
        }

        int newWidth = (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * scale);
        int newHeight = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * scale);

            if(newWidth <= 0 || newHeight <= 0)
            { // Extra check, for invalid width/height
                Log.e("test", "invalid dimension ("+newWidth+"x"+newHeight+")");
                return bitmap;
            }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    }
}
```

To avoid scaling ratio problems use this in your main.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Comment: I just created it now and it crashs on load :-(

Here is the code:

`code
  int percentage = screen_percentage / 100; 
  
  float scale = screen_width / 100 * percentage; 
  
  if(screen_width < screen_height) 
  { 
   scale = screen_height / 100 * percentage; 
  }
  
  int newWidth = (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * scale);
  int newHeight = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * scale);

  // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
  return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);`

Comment: Don't get a chance to see it, the app just crashes.

Comment: If you use eclipse, go to the Debug perspective, watch the output in Logcat window, you should see an error message

Comment: The error is:

01-30 21:22:20.531: E/AndroidRuntime(14844):  at com.forwardapps.live.BattlefieldThread.run(BattlefieldThread.java:42)

Comment: 01-30 21:22:20.531: E/AndroidRuntime(14844): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Comment: So the width and height of your bitmap is 0... Make sure that the Bitmap you pass in as a parameter really is a valid bitmap. I've modified my answer to create a working example

Comment: Yeah it's an actual bitmap I logged out the values of the width and height of it.

In your example you don't use casting? but in my eclipse it gives me an error if I don't? Is there a reason for this?

I copied your example and I'm still getting the error:
01-30 21:32:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14948): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Comment: If it helps the output from width and height of the bitmap was 200x2000 because it's the explosion.

Comment: yep, i've modified the answer -> the problem was in calculating the value of 'percentage'. If percentage is an int, it will be 0 after dividing through 100. Latest edit will work. Good luck, i'm off

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you've save me a great deal of time.

Comment: The only hic I've got not is that the aspect ratio is lost :-|